# Dropdownlist loses its value on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist`  of whose values comes from selection of other list.

So when I select the value from the `dropdownlist` and then click on `button` my selected value gets lost. Below is my js code:-

```
function FunDeptChange(StrPriId,StrPriDeptId)
{
    //fill user
    if(Trim(document.getElementById(StrPriDeptId).value) != "") 
    {
        StrPriFnName = "FunGetUsersInDept("+document.getElementById(StrPriDeptId).value+")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET","FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para="+StrPriFnName,false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");
        if(Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "")
        {
            document.getElementById(StrPriId).innerHTML = "";
            var ObjPriOption = document.createElement("Option");
            ObjPriOption.text = "--- Select ---";
            ObjPriOption.value = "";
            document.getElementById(StrPriId).add(ObjPriOption);

            StrPriRow = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('|');
            for(IntPriI=0; IntPriI<StrPriRow.length-1; IntPriI++)
            {
                StrPriCol = StrPriRow[IntPriI].split('~');
                var ObjPriOption = document.createElement("Option");
                ObjPriOption.text = StrPriCol[1]+" "+StrPriCol[2]+" "+StrPriCol[3];
                ObjPriOption.value = StrPriCol[0];
                document.getElementById(StrPriId).add(ObjPriOption);
            }

            if (document.getElementById('CmbNextAction').value == "8" || document.getElementById('CmbNextAction').value == "4" || document.getElementById('CmbNextAction').value == "12" )
            {
                StrPriFnName = "FunGetDefultDeptUser("+document.getElementById('CmbNextDept').value+ ")";
                var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET","FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para="+StrPriFnName,false);
                ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

                if(Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) == "")
                 {
                     FunMessageBox("Default User of Selected Department has Not define. Please Contact to Administrator",16,StrPriTitle);
                     //document.getElementById('TxtReceiptNo').focus();
                     return false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    document.getElementById('CmbNextUser').value = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('CmbNextUser').disabled=true; 
                 }
                 if(document.getElementById('CmbNextAction').value == "12")
                 {
                        document.getElementById('CmbNextUser').disabled=false; 
                 }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(StrPriId).innerHTML = "";
            var ObjPriOption = document.createElement("Option");
            ObjPriOption.text = "--- Select ---";
            ObjPriOption.value = "";
            document.getElementById(StrPriId).add(ObjPriOption);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(StrPriId).innerHTML = "";
        var ObjPriOption = document.createElement("Option");
        ObjPriOption.text = "--- Select ---";
        ObjPriOption.value = "";
        document.getElementById(StrPriId).add(ObjPriOption);
    }
    //end of code to fill user
}
```

Also see the HTML

```
<select id="CmbNextDept" runat="server" onchange="FunDeptChange('CmbNextUser','CmbNextDept')" >
                                    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                                </select>
```

**UPDATED**

My button looks like something in browser rendered HTML

```
<td onselectstart='javascript:{return false;}' id="ToolbarControl1xSaveToolBar_Item_1"
onmouseover='javascript:igtbar_mouseOver(this,event,true);' onmousedown='javascript:igtbar_mouseDown(this,event,true,false);'
onmouseup='javascript:igtbar_mouseUp(this,event,true);' onmouseout='javascript:igtbar_mouseOut(this,event,true,false);'
class="button_bar_default" title="Save & Exit">
<img style='margin: 0;' igimg='1' src='/Erp/Images/save_exit.gif' align='Left' id='ToolbarControl1xSaveToolBar_Item_1_img' />
<span igtxt='1'>Save & Exit</span>
```

Comment: are you using `asp.net`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: yes, my form is in `asp.net`

Comment: then look at the page_load event, you might be doing something in there

Comment: What button? If it is a submit or just not type="button" then your page may be reloading

Comment: @mplungjan: it is something like `<uc1:ToolbarControl OnSaveClick="ToolbarControl1_SaveClick" ID="ToolbarControl1"
                        HeaderText="" OnSaveAndContinueClick="ToolbarControl1_SaveAndClick" runat="server" />`

Comment: @mplungjan: updated the code for reference.

Comment: @Bharadwaj: there is nothing in page_load, but there is something on button click. let me know if u want that code too ?

Comment: That would be useful. Also look in console

Comment: @mplungjan: how to check console in IE ?

Comment: aah, got it, but there is no error in console

Comment: @Bharadwaj: is it something useful `if (TxtMode.Value.Trim() == "H")
            {
                StrPriDetails = Request.QueryString["Inward_Mkey"].ToString() + "~" + Request.Form["CmbCurrentStatus"] + "~" + Request.Form["CmbDept"] + "~" + Request.Form["CmbUser"] + "~" + DtmCurrentDateTime.Value + "~" + TxtRemarks.Value + "~" + Request.Form["CmbNextAction"] + "~" + Request.Form["CmbNextDept"] + "~" + StrPriNextUser + StrPriOtherDetails + "~" + strReceiptNo + "~" + strDocNo + "~" + strPoNo + "|";
            }`